# glColor, glMatrixMode mysteriously giving "Invalid operation" errors

Tags: opengl, luagl

Recently my game-engine-in-progress has started throwing OpenGL errors in places that they shouldn't be possible. After rendering a few frames, suddenly I start getting errors from glColor:

```
print(gl.GetError()) --> nil
gl.Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
print(gl.GetError()) --> INVALID_OPERATION
```

If I don't call glColor here, I later get an invalid operation error from glMatrixMode.

According to the GL manual, glColor should never raise an error, and glMatrixMode only if it's between glBegin and glEnd, which I've checked is not the case. Are there any other reasons these functions can raise an error, that I'm not aware of? Maybe related to render-to-texture/renderbuffer extensions? I've been debugging like mad and can't find anything that should cause such failures. The whole program is a bit too large and complex to post here. It's using luagl, which is just a thin wrapper around the OpenGL API, and SDL. The reported version is: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.2

Answer (score 1):

glColor will result in an error if there is no active OpenGL context. If you are using multiple contexts or glBindFramebuffer check that you always switch ones that are valid. Also remember that using OpenGL calls from multiple threads require [special attention](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading).

Comment: OpenGL contexts can be moved between contexts just fine. There's no confinement of an OpenGL context to the creating thread. You just need to unbind and rebind for context migration.

Comment: I'm not doing any of that, but is it possible I'm losing my GL context somehow?

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48535
Looks like this was actually a driver bug. >.>